# Access rights for Tasks

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

When i create project with Privacy / Visibility Private Project Followers only the Task in this Project are visible only for user that are followers or assigned to the task.

How can i do that if there is no followers and Task is not assigned to anyone that every user may see that task.

Is this made trough  Access Rights/Rules ?

The thing is by the Assignet To i have clear button and if user pushes that button it clears Assigned person from task, so after that i want that that task without assignment would be visible to everyone

Comment: if it's seen by the administrator`SUPERUSER` then it's don by `ir.rules` so when you login as administrator you can see that task if not then it's filtered by domain action

Comment: yes i can see that task as SUPERUSER , and it's probably in <record model="ir.rule" id="task_visibility_rule"> just still can't figure out how "domain_force" should look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to update any record in odoo that is saved by xml record you should do this:

```xml
 <record "original_module_name.original_id" model="model.name">
    ...
    ..
  </record>
```

in your case :

```xml
 <record model="ir.rule" id="project.task_visibility_rule">
     <field name="domain_force">[
    '|',
        ('user_id', '=', False) ,
        '|',
            ('project_id.privacy_visibility', 'in', ['portal', 'employees']),
            '|',
                '&amp;',
                    ('project_id.privacy_visibility', '=', 'followers'),
                    ('project_id.message_partner_ids', 'in', [user.partner_id.id]),
                '|',
                    ('message_partner_ids', 'in', [user.partner_id.id]),
                    # to subscribe check access to the record, follower is not enough at creation
                    ('user_id', '=', user.id)
    ]</field>
</record>
```

one thing is that this happen in the first time you install the model. most time when you upgrade the model nothing is happen so uninstall the module and reinstalle it when you are testing your domain.
i didn't try the domain but hope it work.

Comment: if that task don't belong to any one: `('user_id', '=', False)`

Comment: yeh i figured out that it's just so simple as user_id = False... , but thank you for your help :)